# filename change using HTML/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I automatically change the file-name in HTML / CSS / or JavaScript for the following piece of HTML code?

```
<img src="photos/BFJAN.JPG" alt="" style="border: 2px solid ; width: 230px; height: 171px;">
```

I'm trying to change `"JAN"` in the file-name to `"FEB"` depending on the data in an XML file I get from JavaScript:

```
var z=0;    //0 for JAN, 1 for FEB  from an XML file tag <ShortMonth>

dataShortMonth=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ShortMonth")[z].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
```

Each month I want to just change the z variable without having to change all the file-names manually to display different images.

Comment: you cant alter a server based file system with client side code. youll need a server side scripting language such as php

Comment: Take a look at knockout.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Html**

```
<img id="photo" src="photos/BFJAN.JPG" alt="" style="border: 2px solid ; width: 230px; height: 171px;">
```

**JS**

```
var nValue = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ShortMonth")[0].innerHtml;
document.getElementById("photo").src = "photos/BF" + (nValue == "0" ? "JAN" : "FEB")+ ".JPG";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is as easy as reading the current month from the current date

```
var z = new Date().getMonth(); // z=1 in February
```

helpfully for you, months are zero-based in javascript!